# Ferramenta para desenho de gráficos em java

Tags: java

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma ferramenta com IReport que eu possa utilizar para fazer um gráfico parecido com essa imagem. Já utilizei o JFreechart, mas não consegui deixar parecido! Os valores das barras tem que ficar em baixo e os rótulos em cima conforme a imagem. 
[image: gráfico de barras que eu quero]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acho que talvez você tenha que desenhar os gráficos na mão. Fiz um programa que faz isso.

Aqui está o código:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class GraficoDeBarras {

    // Formato é AARRGGBB, aonde A é o alpha, R é o vermelho, G é o verde e B é o azul.
    private static final int AZUL = 0xFF99D8EA;
    private static final int VERMELHO = 0xFFEA9999;

    private final int larguraRetangulo;
    private final int alturaRetangulo;
    private final int alturaTotal;
    private final int yBaseBarra;
    private final int xBaseBarra;
    private final int larguraBarra;
    private final int profundidade;
    private final int yRetangulo;
    private final int yRotulo;
    private final int yValor;

    public GraficoDeBarras(
            int larguraRetangulo,
            int alturaRetangulo,
            int alturaTotal,
            int yBase,
            int xBase,
            int larguraBarra,
            int profundidade,
            int yRetangulo,
            int yRotulo,
            int yValor)
    {
        this.larguraRetangulo = larguraRetangulo;
        this.alturaRetangulo = alturaRetangulo;
        this.alturaTotal = alturaTotal;
        this.yBaseBarra = yBase;
        this.xBaseBarra = xBase;
        this.larguraBarra = larguraBarra;
        this.profundidade = profundidade;
        this.yRetangulo = yRetangulo;
        this.yRotulo = yRotulo;
        this.yValor = yValor;
    }

    private static class Barra {
        private final int alturaBarra;
        private final int cor;
        private final String valor;
        private final String rotulo;

        public Barra(int alturaBarra, int cor, String valor, String rotulo) {
            this.alturaBarra = alturaBarra;
            this.cor = (cor & 0x00FFFFFF) | 0xFF000000; // Elimina a transparência.
            this.valor = valor;
            this.rotulo = rotulo;
        }

        public void desenhar(GraficoDeBarras grafico, int x, int y, Graphics2D g) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Color preenchimento = new Color(cor);

            // Desenha as bordas externas.
            int x1 = x;
            int x2 = x + grafico.larguraRetangulo - 1;
            int y1 = y + grafico.yRetangulo;
            int y2 = y + grafico.yRetangulo + grafico.alturaRetangulo - 1;
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1);
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2);
            g.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2);
            g.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2);

            // Prepara o desenho do paralelepípedo.
            int xBarra1 = x1 + grafico.xBaseBarra;
            int xBarra2 = x1 + grafico.xBaseBarra + grafico.larguraBarra;
            int yBarra1 = y1 + grafico.yBaseBarra;
            int yBarra2 = y1 + grafico.yBaseBarra - alturaBarra;

            // Se a altura for negativa, precisará inverter o yBarra2 e o yBarra1.
            if (yBarra2 > yBarra1) {
                int t = yBarra2;
                yBarra2 = yBarra1;
                yBarra1 = t;
            }

            // Desenha as bordas frontais do paralelepípedo.
            int[] xFrente = {xBarra1, xBarra1, xBarra2, xBarra2};
            int[] yFrente = {yBarra1, yBarra2, yBarra2, yBarra1};
            g.setColor(preenchimento);
            g.fillPolygon(xFrente, yFrente, 4);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawPolygon(xFrente, yFrente, 4);

            // Desenha as bordas laterais do paralelepípedo.
            int[] xLateral = {xBarra2, xBarra2, xBarra2 + grafico.profundidade, xBarra2 + grafico.profundidade};
            int[] yLateral = {yBarra1, yBarra2, yBarra2 - grafico.profundidade, yBarra1 - grafico.profundidade};
            g.setColor(preenchimento);
            g.fillPolygon(xLateral, yLateral, 4);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawPolygon(xLateral, yLateral, 4);

            // Desenha as bordas superiores do paralelepípedo.
            int[] xSuperior = {xBarra1, xBarra1 + grafico.profundidade, xBarra2 + grafico.profundidade, xBarra2};
            int[] ySuperior = {yBarra2, yBarra2 - grafico.profundidade, yBarra2 - grafico.profundidade, yBarra2};
            g.setColor(preenchimento);
            g.fillPolygon(xSuperior, ySuperior, 4);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawPolygon(xSuperior, ySuperior, 4);

            // Escreve o valor e o rótulo.
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int larguraValor = fm.charsWidth(valor.toCharArray(), 0, valor.length());
            int larguraRotulo = fm.charsWidth(rotulo.toCharArray(), 0, rotulo.length());
            g.drawString(valor, x + (grafico.larguraRetangulo - larguraValor) / 2, y + grafico.yValor);
            g.drawString(rotulo, x + (grafico.larguraRetangulo - larguraRotulo) / 2, y + grafico.yRotulo);
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage desenharBarras(List<Barra> barras) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage((larguraRetangulo - 1) * barras.size() + 1, alturaTotal, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
        int x = 0;
        for (Barra b : barras) {
            b.desenhar(this, x, 0, g);
            x += larguraRetangulo - 1;
        }
        return bi;
    }

    public static final class Dado {
        private final int valor;
        private final String rotulo;

        public Dado(int valor, String rotulo) {
            this.valor = valor;
            this.rotulo = rotulo;
        }

        public int getValor() {
            return valor;
        }

        public String getRotulo() {
            return rotulo;
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage desenhar(int alturaTotalDasBarras, List<Dado> dados) {
        if (dados == null || dados.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Apenas uma lista de dados não-vazia pode ter um gráfico gerado.");
        }
        if (alturaTotalDasBarras < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("A altura total das barras deve ser de no mínimo 2 pixels.");
        }

        // Define detalhes fixos das dimensões do gráfico.
        int larguraBarra = 40;
        int profundidade = 10;
        int margem = 10;
        int yRetangulo = 20;

        // Encontra o maior e o menor valor e o tamanho da faixa de valores. Sempre considerando que 0 está dentro desta faixa.
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        for (Dado d : dados) {
            int valor = d.getValor();
            if (valor > max) max = valor;
            if (valor < min) min = valor;
        }
        int variacao = Math.max(1, max - min); // min nunca será positivo. Se todos os números forem zeros, não queremos dividir por zero.

        // Agora que "variacao" foi calculada, percorre a lista novamente para calcular a altura de cada barra em pixels.
        List<Barra> lista = new ArrayList<Barra>(dados.size());
        for (Dado d : dados) {
            int valor = d.getValor();
            int altura = (int) (((double) valor) * alturaTotalDasBarras / variacao);
            Barra barra = new Barra(altura, valor >= 0 ? AZUL : VERMELHO, String.valueOf(d.getValor()), d.getRotulo());
            lista.add(barra);
        }

        // Recalcula os tamanhos das barras em pixels ao invés dos valores brutos.
        int maxPixels = (int) (((double) max) * alturaTotalDasBarras / variacao);
        int minPixels = (int) (((double) min) * alturaTotalDasBarras / variacao);
        int variacaoPixels = Math.max(1, maxPixels - minPixels); // min nunca será positivo.

        // Calcula os demais detalhes das dimensões do gráfico.
        int larguraRetangulo = larguraBarra + profundidade + 2 * margem;
        int alturaRetangulo = variacaoPixels + profundidade + 2 * margem;
        int alturaTotal = alturaRetangulo + 40;
        int yBase = alturaRetangulo + minPixels - margem;
        int yRotulo = yRetangulo - 4;
        int yValor = alturaTotal - 4;

        // Cria e desenha o gráfico.
        GraficoDeBarras g = new GraficoDeBarras(larguraRetangulo, alturaRetangulo, alturaTotal, yBase, margem, larguraBarra, profundidade, yRetangulo, yRotulo, yValor);
        return g.desenharBarras(lista);
    }

    public static BufferedImage desenharTamanhoFixo(int larguraTotal, int alturaTotal, List<Dado> dados) {
        if (dados == null || dados.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Apenas uma lista de dados não-vazia pode ter um gráfico gerado.");
        }

        // Define detalhes fixos das dimensões do gráfico.
        int profundidade = 10;
        int margem = 10;
        int yRetangulo = 20;

        // Calcula detalhes sobre a altura e largura.
        int alturaRetangulo = alturaTotal - 40;
        int alturaTotalDasBarras = alturaRetangulo - profundidade - 2 * margem;
        if (alturaTotalDasBarras <= 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A altura da imagem é insuficiente.");
        int larguraRetangulo = 1 + ((larguraTotal - 1) / dados.size());
        int larguraBarra = larguraRetangulo - profundidade - 2 * margem;
        if (larguraBarra <= 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("A largura da imagem é insuficiente.");

        // Encontra o maior e o menor valor e o tamanho da faixa de valores. Sempre considerando que 0 está dentro desta faixa.
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        for (Dado d : dados) {
            int valor = d.getValor();
            if (valor > max) max = valor;
            if (valor < min) min = valor;
        }
        int variacao = Math.max(1, max - min); // min nunca será positivo. Se todos os números forem zeros, não queremos dividir por zero.

        // Agora que "variacao" foi calculada, percorre a lista novamente para calcular a altura de cada barra em pixels.
        List<Barra> lista = new ArrayList<Barra>(dados.size());
        for (Dado d : dados) {
            int valor = d.getValor();
            int altura = (int) (((double) valor) * alturaTotalDasBarras / variacao);
            Barra barra = new Barra(altura, valor >= 0 ? AZUL : VERMELHO, String.valueOf(d.getValor()), d.getRotulo());
            lista.add(barra);
        }

        // Recalcula os tamanhos das barras em pixels ao invés dos valores brutos.
        int minPixels = (int) (((double) min) * alturaTotalDasBarras / variacao);

        // Calcula os demais detalhes das dimensões do gráfico.
        int yBase = alturaRetangulo + minPixels - margem;
        int yRotulo = yRetangulo - 4;
        int yValor = alturaTotal - 4;

        // Cria e desenha o gráfico.
        GraficoDeBarras g = new GraficoDeBarras(larguraRetangulo, alturaRetangulo, alturaTotal, yBase, margem, larguraBarra, profundidade, yRetangulo, yRotulo, yValor);
        return g.desenharBarras(lista);
    }
}
```

Para testar eu fiz esta classe:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 * @author Victor
 */
public class FazGrafico {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GraficoDeBarras.Dado> dados = Arrays.asList(
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(5, "Janeiro"),
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(8, "Fevereiro"),
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(3, "Março"),
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(0, "Abril"),
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(14, "Maio"),
                new GraficoDeBarras.Dado(-5, "Junho"));
        BufferedImage imagem = GraficoDeBarras.desenharTamanhoFixo(500, 180, dados);
        //BufferedImage imagem = GraficoDeBarras.desenhar(100, dados);
        // Java 8: EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> mostraImagem(imagem));
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mostraImagem(imagem);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void mostraImagem(BufferedImage imagem) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Teste do gráfico");
        JPanel jp = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(imagem, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        jf.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imagem.getWidth(), imagem.getHeight()));
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        jf.setLocation((screen.width - jf.getWidth()) / 2, (screen.height - jf.getHeight()) / 2);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

E aqui está alguns dos gráficos gerados:

Este é utilizando `GraficoDeBarras.desenhar(100, dados)` com os valores `{5, 8, 3, 0, 14}`:

[image: gráfico 1]

Este é utilizando `GraficoDeBarras.desenhar(100, dados)` com os valores `{5, 8, 3, 0, 14, -5}`:

[image: gráfico 2]

Este é utilizando `GraficoDeBarras.desenharTamanhoFixo(500, 180, dados)` com os valores `{5, 8, 3, 0, 14, -5}`:

[image: gráfico 3]

No método `desenhar`, o primeiro parâmetro é a altura máxima que a face frontal de uma barra pode ter. Os demais valores necessários para calcular o tamanho da imagem, bem como o tamanho e posição dos seus elementos são baseados nisso.

No método `desenharTamanhoFixo`, o primeiro parâmetro é a largura total da imagem e o segundo é a altura total. Os demais valores necessários para calcular o tamanho e posição dos seus elementos são baseados nisso.

Em ambos os métodos, as barras tem 10 pixels de profundidade e uma margem de 10 pixels para as bordas do retângulo na direita, esquerda, abaixo e acima. Também há uma margem de 20 pixels acima e abaixo dos retângulos aonde serão colocados os valores e os rótulos, que tem cada um a sua *baseline* 4 pixels acima da borda inferior da respectiva faixa. No caso do método `desenhar`, a face frontal da barra sempre tem 40 pixels de largura. As cores usadas para os positivos são o azul `0xFF99D8EA` (RGB = (153, 216, 234)) e para os negativos o vermelho `0xFFEA9999` (RGB = (234, 153, 153)). Mudar isso não deverá ser algo difícil ou trabalhoso.

Além disso, o código é bastante flexível para você colocar as variações que quiser, tal como evidenciado no construtor da classe `GraficoDeBarras`. Você não deverá ter grandes dificuldades para alterar a largura e a profundidade das barras, o tamanho das margens entre as barras e as bordas do retângulo que as contém, a largura e altura destes retângulos, as cores, as posições do texto, e obviamente os valores e os rótulos, entre outras possibilidades.

Comment: Olá Victor agradeço sua ajuda. Gostaria de saber qual versão do java você esta usando, porque esta dando erro nessa parte que tem esse valores: 0xFF_99_D8_EA : 0xFF_EA_99_99

Comment: Victor tem como eu fazer espaçamento nos rotulos?

Comment: @RenatoRomão Estou usando o Java 8. A partir do Java 7 é permitido usar `_` em literais numéricos. Exemplo: `1_234_567` ao invés de `1234567`. Para o Java 6 ou inferior você terá que remover os `_` (fica `0xFF99D8EA : 0xFFEA9999`). Além disso aonde está `ArrayList<>` só funciona do Java 7 para cima, no java 6 deverá ser `ArrayList<Barra>`. Por fim, no programa de exemplo, estou usando `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> mostraImagem(imagem));`, que no Java 7 e inferior terá que usar a classe anônima: `EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { mostraImagem(imagem); } });`.

Comment: @RenatoRomão O que você quer dizer exatamente por "espaçamento nos rótulos?"

Comment: @RenatoRomão Alterei o código para ser compatível com Java 6. Além disso coloquei uns comentários para explicar o 0xFF99D8EA e o 0xFFEA9999.

Comment: Deixar os rotulo centralizado junto com as barras. Tipo ficar na mesma posição das barras.

Comment: Victor é deixar os rotulo centralizado para ficar na mesma posição das barras

Comment: @RenatoRomão Implementado. Centralizei os rótulos e atualizei as figuras. :)

Comment: Vitor obrigado, já estou conseguindo fazer que eu precisava, me ajudou bastante esse código. Uma duvia eu consigo deixar um tamanho fixo na imagem tipo Largura e altura é porque eu vou usar isso no ireport passando uma imagem.

Comment: @RenatoRomão Calma aí que estou tentando dar um jeito nisso...

Comment: Vitor eu já conseguir fazer, faço ele desenhar as bordas externas, mas não desenhar as barras. Era bem isso mesmo que eu precisava. Agora eu consigo fazer 15 colunas mesmo sem aparecer as barrinhas.

Comment: @RenatoRomão Consegui mesmo assim, veja o método `desenharTamanhoFixo`. Também aproveitei a oportunidade para melhorar um pouco a organização do código e acrescentar mais comentários.

Comment: Victor agradeço pela sua atenção. Esse código me ajudou muito...

Comment: @RenatoRomão Valeu, foi até divertido desenvolvê-lo. :)